# Make a TLSv1.2 request with HTTP2

Tags: c++, https, tls1.2, http2

Im trying make a POST request to a server using TLSv1.2.

The problems i have here are:

> How to make a connection with TLSv1.2 secure socket layer ?
>
> How to HPACK the headers ?
>
> How to send the **body**(DATA) to same stream i think that is via the Stream identifier flag but i don't know how to do it programatically.

On the **next picture** you have an example about what im trying to reproduce in c++:

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huGyt.png)

I think this [WSAConnect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsaconnect) function can work with TLSv1.2 connection but i'm not sure at all.

I try too [HPACK encoder/decoder](https://github.com/jnferguson/hpack-rfc7541) header but when i import the header on Visual Studio 2017 gives me some errors in 4 or 5 lines.

And finally send DATA to the same stream, i think the data via TLSv1.2 need by encrypted but no compressed like the HEADERS.

My question is how can i do it programatically in c++ ?

With simple example and good explanation is sufficient.

**EDIT1:**

I find openssl client for c++, looks like work with TLSv1.2

Comment: What have you tried? What does your current code look like?

Comment: I don't do anything because im getting errors on HPACK encoder/decoder, but the first step was using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/using-secure-socket-extensions so, this is the connection, but im not sure if this perform TLSv1.2, after that i need create HPACK for headers but idk how to do it

Comment: Winsock has no concept of TLS. You need to use a TLS API/library on top of the socket, such as Microsoft's SChannel, OpenSSL, etc. Otherwise, use an HTTP API/library that handles its own socket connections for you, such as Microsoft's WinInet/WinHTTP, libcurl, etc. Don't implement HTTP/TLS manually, they are very complex protocols